# Symfony phpunit testing getUser()

Tags: symfony, phpunit

Как протестировать в контроллере

```
$rq->setCreatedBy($this->getUser());
```

такую строку в частности как добавить в security.context или сессию обьект юзера?

Делаю что-то наподобии пробовал разные варианты не получается ...

```
$token = $this->getMockBuilder(\Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface::class)->getMock();
        $token->expects($this->any())
                  ->method('getUser')
                  ->willReturn($user);

            $service = $this->getMockBuilder(\Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface::class)
                  ->disableOriginalConstructor()
                  ->getMock();
            $service->expects($this->any())
                  ->method('getToken')
                  ->willReturn($token);        

            $client4->getContainer()->set('security.token_storage', $service);
```

Comment: $this->getUser() же повсюду используется разве никто не тестировать это?)

Comment: А что вообще такое `$rq` и что делает `setCreatedBy`?

Comment: Просто есть у меня такое чувство, что вы пытаетесь использовать модульные тесты там, где нужны функциональные.

Comment: $rq это обьект в который я добавляю через ситтер setCreatedBy юзера взятого с security.storage_token в контроле с помощью $this->getUser() она возвращает обьект юзера под которым ты сейчас авторизован, и мне надо вообщем сделать мок token interface, user и.т.д добавить его в контайнер

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что тест контролера должен проверять правильный ли пользователь попадает в `$rq`?

Comment: Да, http_basic аутоинтефикация тут не подходит надо создать файк ( мок ) tokenStorage и поместить это в контайнер.